# How do I automate permissions to the files in the shared folder to be accessible by both the host MacOS and the guest Ubuntu through VirtualBox?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, virtualbox, macosx, shared-folders

I was working towards getting Ubuntu 14.04 set up in a VirtualBox, and I have achieved that. I also have it at the stage where it's mounting my shared folder automatically. The only remaining problem I have is that when I create a file in the shared folder on the Host side (MacOS) or if I create a file on the guest side (Ubuntu) the permissions of the file in the shared folder default to 644 (-rw-r--r--).

This produces the issue where I'm not allowed to actually modify the file that I just created in Ubuntu. Is it possible to have it set so that all folders, files, executables in a folder are set at a permission level that I will be able to create a file, or compile an executable, in the shared folder that both my host and guest will be able to use?